# git identify the most recent intersection of two branches

Tags: git

Is there a shorthand for identifying the last commit common to two branches?
For example if I have master and then topic1 splits off from master, and they both continue

```
master:
a------b------c------d
        \
topic1:  r------s------t
```

Is there a way to identify say `b`?
For example if there was such a thing as master#topic1 (same as topic1#master) that meant, "the most recent commit shared by both master and topic."

I would like to be able to:

```
$ git checkout topic1
$ git diff master#topic1..topic1
```

I know that I can do:

```
git diff master..topic
```

but I don't care about commits `c` and `d`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to the question you're actually asking:

```
git diff master...topic
```

Note the **three** dots.

From the manpage:

> `git diff [--options] <commit>...<commit> [--] [<path>...]`
>
> This form is to view the changes on the branch containing and up to the second , starting at a common ancestor of both `<commit>`. `git diff A...B` is equivalent to `git diff $(git merge-base A B) B`. You can omit any one of `<commit>`, which has the same effect as using `HEAD` instead.

Comment: This gives a diff, but doesn't identify the intersecting commit

Answer (score 10):

use [`git merge-base`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge-base.html).

```
NAME
git-merge-base - Find as good common ancestors as possible for a merge

SYNOPSIS
git merge-base [-a|--all] [--octopus] <commit> <commit>…
git merge-base --independent <commit>…
```

Comment: @orange: There is, in your use case! See my answer.

Comment: This should really be the accepted answer, as it answers the question as actually asked. Something like `git merge-base master topic` would identify the intersecting commit, for the example in the question.